# Gradle: thorntail plugin not found

Tags: gradle, thorntail

I've took a look on thorntail examples [here](https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail-examples/blob/master/gradle-examples/multi-module/build.gradle).

I've created this project:

```
frontoffice
├── gradle.properties
├── build.gradle
└── gradle
    └── thorntail.gradle
```

`thorntail.gradle` is:

```
buildscript {
  String thorntailVersion = System.getProperty('thorntailVersion') ?: VERSION_THORNTAIL

  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "io.thorntail:thorntail-gradle-plugin:$thorntailVersion"
  }
}
```

and `build.gradle`:

```
apply from: "$projectDir/gradle/thorntail.gradle"
apply plugin: 'thorntail'
```

I'm getting:

```
➜  prjt git:(master) ✗ gradle clean compile

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/jeusdi/projects/espaidoc/frontoffice/build.gradle' line: 10

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':frontoffice'.
**> Plugin with id 'thorntail' not found.**
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK plugin IDs cannot be used in *external scripts*. This is a known limitation. Instead you should use the fully qualified plugin class. For example, in `thorntail.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  String thorntailVersion = System.getProperty('thorntailVersion') ?: '2.5.1.Final-SNAPSHOT'
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "io.thorntail:thorntail-gradle-plugin:$thorntailVersion"
  }
}

apply plugin: 'org.wildfly.swarm.plugin.gradle.PackagePlugin'
```

In `build.gradle`:

```
apply from: "$projectDir/gradle/thorntail.gradle"
```

I know that it does not look like what you did, because the `apply` is in the external script. Another option (the closest to what you want to achieve) is in your `build.gradle` to put the following:

```
buildscript {
  apply from: "$projectDir/gradle/thorntail.gradle",
  to: buildscript
}

apply plugin: 'thorntail'
```

Then in `thorntail.gradle` remove the `buildscript` block and leave the internal block, i.e.:

```
String thorntailVersion = System.getProperty('thorntailVersion') ?: '2.5.1.Final-SNAPSHOT'
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "io.thorntail:thorntail-gradle-plugin:$thorntailVersion"
  }
```